# Pass data as a string to argparse in Python: unrecognized argument

Tags: python, date, argparse

I am trying to parse date as an argument in Python with argparse:

```
def parsing(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--b", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--e", type=str)
    return parser

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser = parsing(parser)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I'm trying to execute it with:

```
python file.py –-b 20100101 –-e 20200120
```

But I am getting a "unrecognized argument" error. I have also tried removing the `type=str`, but I get the same error.

```
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs: 
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll 

C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.WCDJNK7YVMPZQ2ME2ZZHJJRJ3JIKNDB7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:" usage: file.py [-h] [--b B] [--e E] file.py: error: unrecognized arguments: –-b 20100101 –-e 20200120
```

Comment: Show the full eror message.

Comment: C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.WCDJNK7YVMPZQ2ME2ZZHJJRJ3JIKNDB7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
usage: file.py [-h] [--b B] [--e E]
file.py: error: unrecognized arguments: –-b 20100101 –-e 20200120

Comment: it doesn't give an error in my case

Comment: Is that EXACTLY how you typed this?  Because you would get that error if you passed those arguments as one string:  `python file.py "--b 20100101 --e 20200120"`

Comment: The difference between the two kinds of `dash` is most obvious in your comments as displayed on my tablet.  With other fonts there's just a slight difference in character length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in this line.

```
python file.py –-b 20100101 –-e 20200120
```

one of the '-' is a different character.

```
python file.py --b 20100101 --e 20200120
```

This works.

Comment: Good eye, by the way.